# How to recursively merge arrays with same key?

Tags: php, arrays

Below is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 1 
            [branch_id] => 4
            [total] => 2254.35
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 1  
            [branch_id] => 4
            [total] => 31989.2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 3  
            [branch_id] => 5
            [total] => 2109.71
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 1  
            [branch_id] => 4
            [total] => 200
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 1  
            [branch_id] => 4
            [total] => 200
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 2  
            [branch_id] => 6
            [total] => 550
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 2  
            [branch_id] => 6
            [total] => 550
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 1  
            [branch_id] => 4
            [total] => 400
        )

)
```

As you can see there are multiple arrays with same key and same value. Now, I want to merge arrays which have same value in `transaction_id` key. The new array would be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 1  
            [branch_id] => 4 //always replace this element
            [total] => 35043.55 //always sum this element(i.e. 2254.35 + 31989.2 + 200 + 200 + 400)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 3  
            [branch_id] => 5
            [total] => 2109.71
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 2  
            [branch_id] => 6
            [total] => 1100 //i.e. 550 + 550
        )

)
```

How do I do it. I tried doing with `array_merge_recursive()` but no luck.

Comment: You'll need to write something custom for this.

Comment: @JonStirling yeah, I figured. I was hoping if anyone would provide me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, but does the trick. (See comments)

```
$transactions = [
    [
        'transaction_id' => 1,
        'branch_id' => 4,
        'total' => 200,
    ],
    [
        'transaction_id' => 1,
        'branch_id' => 4,
        'total' => 200,
    ],
    [
        'transaction_id' => 2,
        'branch_id' => 4,
        'total' => 200,
    ],
    [
        'transaction_id' => 3,
        'branch_id' => 4,
        'total' => 200,
    ],
    [
        'transaction_id' => 1,
        'branch_id' => 4,
        'total' => 200,
    ],
    [
        'transaction_id' => 1,
        'branch_id' => 4,
        'total' => 200,
    ],
];

$merged = [];

foreach($transactions as $singleTransaction){
    // Group via transaction_id and clone it for base data //
    if(empty($merged[$singleTransaction['transaction_id']])){
        $merged[$singleTransaction['transaction_id']] = $singleTransaction;
    } else {
        // Add up the totals of duplicate transaction_ids //
        $merged[$singleTransaction['transaction_id']]['total'] += $singleTransaction['total'];
    }
}
```

Comment: This kind of thing makes it really difficult to tell people that SO isn't a place where people will do their work for them.

Comment: Well, in this case...
It seemed like a lack of experience, but they'll learn from this.
Hopefully see how simple it was and reflect on that.

Comment: @AneesSaban I appreciate your time and effort. Though this method is still somehow static. But with this, I can get on the track. Thanks !

Comment: @RabinLama Static?

Comment: @AneesSaban yes. You are directly using the key name (i.e. `transaction_id`) not the `$key`

Comment: It groups the data by transaction_id, but adds up the totals. Branch_id stays the same, right? So it's not "static" :P. Unless I'm missing something... Haha

Answer (score 2):

I had similar task to do, you really have to do a custom   code for it. 
I had some simple loop

```
$new_array=array();
Foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if (isset($new_array[$value[transaction_id]]){
      //add sum and what you want to do 
    }else{
       //add new record
    }
}
```

this is not the best but it will do what you want
and don't forget to `unset()` the used rows to save data

Answer (score 1):

My intuitive solution:

```
$arr = Array
(
    0 => Array
    (
        'transaction_id' => 1,
            'branch_id' => 4,
            'total' => 2254.35
        ),

    1 => Array
(
    'transaction_id' => 1,
            'branch_id' => 4,
            'total' => 31989.2
        ),
    2 => Array
(
    'transaction_id' => 3,
            'branch_id' => 5,
            'total' => 2109.71
        ),
    3 => Array
(
    'transaction_id' => 1,
            'branch_id' => 4,
            'total' => 200
        ),
    4 => Array
(
    'transaction_id' => 1,
            'branch_id' => 4,
            'total' => 200
        ),
    5 => Array
(
    'transaction_id' => 2,
            'branch_id' => 6,
            'total' => 550
        ),
    6 => Array
(
    'transaction_id' => 2,
            'branch_id' => 6,
            'total' => 550
        ),
    7 => Array
(
    'transaction_id' => 1,
            'branch_id' => 4,
            'total' => 400
        )
);

$transactionMap = [];
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $currentTransaction = $transactionMap[$item['transaction_id']];
    $currentTransaction['branch_id'] = $item['branch_id'];
    $currentTransaction['total'] = (isset($currentTransaction['total'])?$currentTransaction['total']:0)+$item['total'];
    $transactionMap[$item['transaction_id']] = $currentTransaction;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$aTmp = array();
$aData = ...your data array..
$aRes = array();

foreach ($aData as $row) {
    if (!isset($aTmp[$row['transaction_id']])) {
        $aTmp[$row['transaction_id']] = $row;
    } else {
        $aTmp[$row['transaction_id']]['branch_id'] = $row['branch_id'];
        $aTmp[$row['transaction_id']]['total'] += $row['total'];
    }
}

$aRes = array_values($aTmp);
var_dump($aRes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say all arrays are ready to merge and nested in one master array

define a temp array to hold calculations results

```
$allArrays = [...]; // nest all arrays here
$matchedArrays = [];
foreach($allArrays as $id=>$toMerge) {
   foreach($toMerge as $iid=>$data) {
      if(isset($matchedArrays[$data['transaction_id']])) {
         // process merging here
         $matchedArrays[$data['transaction_id']] = [
            'transaction_id' => $data['transaction_id'],  
            'branch_id' => $data['branch_id'],
            'total' => $matchedArrays[$data['transaction_id']]['total'] + $data['total'],
         ];
      } else {
         $matchedArrays[$data['transaction_id']] = $data;
      }
   }  
}
```

// resulting array will have transaction id as it's keys and merged assoc values